# EclipseLink: Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [type] for the entity class

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, compile-time-weaving

Using EclipseLink 2.5 for JPA. Configured static weaving in Persistence.xml and included steps in Ant build script to run the weaving agent. However when deployed on Weblogic Server, the console shows the following error

> Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute
>   [type] for the entity class

I have found a few similar question on this but none have resolved the issue.

Comment: First, check your jar and inspect one of the classes by decompiling it and see if it really was woven and that it is what you are using on the server.  Then check your persistence.xml to make sure you specified the eclipselink.weaving property with a value of static.  Weblogic supports JPA and EclipseLink natively, so I'm not sure why you would use static weaving instead of dynamic weaving that is built in.  You might also check that it isn't a classloading issue; that you don't have non-woven versions somewhere getting picked up by WLS.

Comment: Verified that weaving is done. New code exists in woven classes. Native support is for dynamic weaving. We have a high volume situation with 90 odd entities and dynamic weaving consumes lot of cpu. Hence want to weave classes statically.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to checkout to have pre-woven classes using static weaving  :  https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).